# Alter default source location for pybuilder

Tags: python, pybuilder

In the [documentation](https://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/tutorial.html#.WfYdeEyZPdR) of `pybuilder` it says that

> The default location for main python sources is
>
> src/main/python
>
> This is a convention borrowed from Apache Maven. You can alter this location...

But it is not mentioned anywhere how to change the code location.
Thanks

Comment: did you try os.chdir() ?

Comment: https://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/manual.html#ProjectAttributes https://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/plugins.html#Pythoncore

Comment: @DRPK I don't want to change the current directory. But `pybuilder` expects the code to be inside` src/main/python`.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for the link :) The solution is to set the property `dir_source_main_python`

    `project.set_property('dir_source_main_python', 'new_source_path')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @jordanm 's comment.

The solution is to set the project property `dir_source_main_python` with the new source location.

```
@init
def initialize(project):
    project.set_property('dir_source_main_python', 'new_source_path')
```