# Pybuilder Unit test unable to find module

Tags: python, pybuilder

Running the unit tests normally works and passes all the tests, but when trying to build using pybuilder it gives me a Build Error:

```
BUILD FAILED - There were 1 error(s) and 0 failure(s) in unit tests (site-packages/pybuilder/plugins/python/unittest_plugin.py:114)
```

[Build Failed message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zarlX.png)

This was caused by the unit test not finding the module it was meant to test.

File layout:

```
.
├── main
│   ├── python
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── utils.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── utils.py
│   └── scripts
│       ├── project.py
│       └── __pycache__
│           └── project.cpython-36.pyc
└── unittest
    └── python
        ├── project_tests.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── project_tests.cpython-36.pyc
        │   └── utils_tests.cpython-36.pyc
        └── utils_tests.py
```

Currently I am importing the module project by:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../../main/scripts')
import project
```

First post and also not a pro Python programmer so I apologize if I missed something to post and/or it is an obvious solution.
I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda late, but i'll just leave it here in case someone needs it :
Usually the **pybuilder** takes the `src/main/python/` folder as the default directory for your scripts, if you want your code to work without adding the `os.path.insert(...)` change the default path (you can find a way to change it in this answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003773/alter-default-source-location-for-pybuilder) )